# How can I create a desktop shortcut for "Listen to this device"?

Tags: windows-7, audio, shortcuts, input

In windows, there is a way to make audio from your input go to your output, by checking "Listen to this device". Is there a way to make a desktop shortcut or start menu shortcut that enables/disables this for a certain device?

On Linux mint I use

```
gst-launch pulsesrc ! pulsesink
```

in a launcher (Linux Mint), and I'm basically wondering how to do something similar in windows.

I know I sound lazy, but I want to do this pretty fast sometimes.